# Variable in c++ wont multiply

Tags: c++

Im working on c++ homework. 
In this project, I need to know the amount received from selling a stock
I get that by multiplying stocks by selling_price. However for some reason when I run the code, the result I get is only the numbers I input as the selling price. Why doesnt the selling_price multiply by the number of stocks?
Thanks in advance.

// ConsoleApplication9.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double stocks ;
    double purchase_price ;
    double selling_price ;

    cout << "Enter number of stocks sold:";
    cin >> stocks ;

    cout << "Enter purchase price:";
    cin >> purchase_price ;

    cout << "Enter selling price:";
    cin >> selling_price ;

    double invested = purchase_price * stocks + (purchase_price * 0.015);
    double total_service_charges = ((purchase_price + selling_price)* (.015 * stocks));

    cout << "Total money invested =" << invested << endl;
    cout << "total service charges=" << total_service_charges << endl;
    cout << "Amount received from selling stocks=" << (selling_price*stocks);

        if (purchase_price < selling_price)
        {cout << "Amount gained=" << selling_price - purchase_price;}
        else if (purchase_price > selling_price)
        {
            cout << "Amount lost=" << purchase_price - selling_price;
        }

        else if (purchase_price = selling_price)
        {
            cout << "Amount gained=" << purchase_price - selling_price<< endl;
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you show what appears on your screen when you run the program, and indicate what's different from what you expected to see.

Comment: [*warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression*](https://godbolt.org/g/agz4ui)

Comment: everything looks fine. Try here http://cpp.sh/7adlo

Comment: Your equations look inconsistent. Is the service fee for buying stocks 1.5% of the price of one stock, or 1.5% of the total price of the stocks purchased?

Comment: Hey I got it to work. Just copied and pasted it into a new archive. I dont know why, but it worked. Thanks for your comments guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (purchase_price = selling_price)
```

You used `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (equality comparison.) What you wanted here is:

```
else if (purchase_price == selling_price)
```

Pay attention to the compiler warnings. In this case, the compiler should have warned you that you're doing an assignment within a conditional expression.